# Liferay 7 How to alert user that they are in offline

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

Is there any way to check if a the user's connection is down and show them a warning that they are in offline connection?

I mean when user login into  liferay portal then do something. After that their internet connection is down. Can I check and show a warning to user that they are in offline ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have SPA.

The easiest way is to ping the server via AJAX and if you don't get a response you are offline. On fail, you'll display a message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom theme, then in your portal_normal file use peice of code #if($is_signed_in).

if you are have any portlet on home page, then do as per the previous comment.